# Custom column not getting updated

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm facing the issue with my custom column `form_id` into users table.

I'm trying to update using `save()` but it didn't update it.

Code:

```
Auth:user()->form_id = $formdata->id;
```

I'm begginer for laravel and need your help.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How you trying to update that?

Comment: if you have a model for that try to add `form_id` to the protected $fillable in your model.

Comment: Updated my question with code

Comment: @HenzJason: Check my answer and let me know it's work OR not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->form_id = $formdata->id;
$user->save();
```

Just make sure that you are using `save` method after filled the variable properly.

Comment: Oh, it's my bad, trying call save method before assignment...thank you so much....

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->update(['form_id'=>$formdata->id]);
```